# Request Parameter Losing Plus Sign

Tags: java, javascript, html, url, escaping

I am editing a search form and trying to protect against special characters in the database. In the JSP search form, a (multiselect) dropdown allows users to select descriptions that will be used in the query (note: descriptions is a list of strings):

```
<select id="descriptionSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <c:forEach items="${descriptions}" var="description">
        <option value="${fn:escapeXml(description)}")}">                            
            <c:out value="${description}" />
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

When the form submits, the page dynamically generates the URL which takes query parameters in the URL (ugly, I know, hands are tied). Here's the snipet making the description segment.

```
var descriptionSelectBox = document.getElementById("descriptionSelect");
var descriptionsUrlAddition = "";

for (var i = 0; i < descriptionSelectBox.options.length; i++) {
    if (descriptionSelectBox.options[i].selected) {
        descriptionsUrlAddition += "&descriptions=" + escape(descriptionSelectBox.options[i].value);
    }
}
```

I have a test entry in the database whose description is:

AAA `~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:";'<>?,./ And wow this has a lot of special characters.

With the code above, for some reason when the request gets to the controller, the description loses the + sign (it becomes just a space).

Does anyone know what might be happening and how to fix it? I am not sure if it's something to do with URLs special use of +, or what. I could edit how the descriptions list is populated (maybe escaping there). If you offer this as a suggestion, please use Java specific code (no Apache escape utils classes, etc).

If it helps, using alerts in the JavaScript indicate that the + sign is not being transformed before sending the request.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`+` means "space" in URLs. Replace it with `%2B`. You could do this just after composing `descriptionsUrlAddition`, for example.

```
descriptionsUrlAddition = descriptionsUrlAddition.replace("+", "%2B");
```

Comment: How would you implement this though?

Comment: @Rachel G., simply replace all `+` signs with `%2B` in the URL string. Once your URL is composed and you have it as a string, you can just use `String`'s `replace()` method. Added example.

Comment: Add the code (escape(descriptionSelectBox.options[i].value).replace("+", "%2B")) to your answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks =)

Comment: @Rachel G., even better, replace it in the whole string. It would be more efficient, since you'll only call `replace()` once.

Comment: not working for me, I have a url with + signs replaced them to %2B, but no use.

Comment: Note that `+` means space only in the **query string** when submitting form data. [more info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100331-00/?p=14443)

Answer (score 3):

For javascript you should use [encodeURIComponent()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) or [encodeuri()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp). For Example:

```
var uri = "fj74cvg+fd1==ee";
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

and res would be encoded to `"fj74cvg%2Bfd1%3D%3Dee"`

For php you can use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). For Example:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
?>
```

These functions will replace any special characters in the string to be used as part of the url.

Comment: `encodeURI()` doesn't change `+` to `%2B`.  Only `encodeURIComponent()` does.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in the front side The javascript encodeuri function to encode your parameters.