# Java Rest Web Service: '+' character inside String param is treated as space character

Tags: java, string, escaping

My client app sends a String to the servers side to decode it. The String in question may contain '+' characters.
My problem is when i want to treat the String, it seams that the '+' chars are gone (probably treated as concatenation operators. How could I solve this problem? Is String not the right type for that? Should I use Byte[] instead?

Client Side:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "my/url/DecryptString",
    data: "encryptedString="+$("#myStringInput").val(),
    ...
```

Code on Server Side:

```
 ...
 public String decryptString(@QueryParam("encryptedString") String encryptedString) {
        logger.info("=====> decryptString()");

        String decryptedString = null;
        Properties properties = new Properties();

            logger.debug("encryptedString: " + encryptedString);

        // get crypto properties
        try {
          properties.load(toto.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            logger.error(e1.getStackTrace());
        }
        if(properties.isEmpty()) {
            logger.error("Properties file is EMPTY!");
        }
        String encodeKey = properties.getProperty("toto.crypt.encodeKey");

        decryptedString = Crypto.Decrypt(encodeKey, encryptedString.toString());

        return decryptedString;
    }
```

The String passed as the encrypted string on client side is: '7NFASg++qLOSfDXBR8wzcw=='

Here are the traces on server side:

> DEBUG encryptedString: 7NFASg  qLOSfDXBR8wzcw==

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` in query params are treated as encodings for spaces, that's why `7NFASg++qLOSfDXBR8wzcw==` is decoded as `7NFASg qLOSfDXBR8wzcw==`. If you want to transport a `+` through a query param, encode it as `%2B` (see also [Request Parameter Losing Plus Sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842547/request-parameter-losing-plus-sign)).