# How to get parameters value as it is from the URL with JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I have a value like var=`P+q+EvhE951eg/I5nz1vi/w2YpJdH+v/vSPaQNg/I=`

I pass this parameter in `url` like

`http://localhost/proj/home.jsp?var=P+q+EvhE951eg/I5nz1vi/w2YpJdH+v/vSPaQNg/I=`

Now In home.jsp i want to use this value of var as it is.But when i do

`String var=request.getParameter("var");` var get the value

`"P q EvhE951eg/I5nz1vi/w2YpJdH v/vSPaQNg/I="` notice it replace `+` with `space`.

So can anyone help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You need to encode the parameters before sending it

Comment: That parameter is already encoded

Comment: Your container may be selectively decoding the text without your say-so. You might want to research the encoding configs for your specific container. or just replace all spaces with the + yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding params like this:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String param = "P+q+EvhE951eg/I5nz1vi/w2YpJdH+v/vSPaQNg/I=";
        System.out.printf("Orginal Param: %s\n", param);
        param = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(param, "utf-8");
        System.out.printf("Encoded Param: %s\n", param);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Orginal Param: P+q+EvhE951eg/I5nz1vi/w2YpJdH+v/vSPaQNg/I=
Encoded Param: P%2Bq%2BEvhE951eg%2FI5nz1vi%2Fw2YpJdH%2Bv%2FvSPaQNg%2FI%3D
```

Answer (score 0):

"+" means "space" in Url. you can replce this with %2B.

For Example

```
queryString = queryString.replace('+', '%2B');
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842547/request-parameter-losing-plus-sign)

if there is only one parameter in the Query string.

you can also get this through request.getQueryString() - Here no need of replace query string.

```
String urlContent = request.getQueryString();
```

Output : var=P+q+EvhE951eg/I5nz1vi/w2YpJdH+v/vSPaQNg/I=