# Why Spring Boot cannot parse view with + symbol?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a controller and two jsp.

When I access `/test1` return status code `404`. But `/test2` is return `200`.

Why Spring Boot cannot parse `+` symbol?

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("test1")
    public String test1() {
        return "/WEB-INF/views/IE10+.jsp";
    }
    @GetMapping("test2")
    public String test2() {
        return "/WEB-INF/views/IE10.jsp";
    }
}
```

I see same problem:
[Request Parameter Losing Plus Sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842547/request-parameter-losing-plus-sign)

But I input `/test1`, it is not contain `+` in The URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file named `Demo+.java` will not get compiled.

Ultimately jsp is nothing but a java file so you should use java coding convention.

According to [coding convension for jsps](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html) you should not use any name which might create any problem.

Use **`IE10plus.jsp`** instead.

Comment: Oh! Thank! I did not expect to be related to java compilation.